# UISwitch in TableView in Switch

Tags: swift, tableview, uiswitch

Hello fellow programmers!  I have a challenge I need help with.  I have built a table using a Custom Style Cell.

This cell simply has a `Label` and `UISwitch`.  The label displays a name and the switch displays whether they are an Admin or not.  This works perfectly.  My challenge is how and where do I put code to react when the switch is changed.

So if I click the switch to change it from off to on where can I get it to print the persons name?  If I can get the name to print I can do the php/sql code myself.  Thanks and here is a snippet from my code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell
    let admin = self.admin[indexPath.row]

    let text1a = admin.FirstName
    let text1aa = " "

    let text1b = admin.LastName
    let text1 = text1a + text1aa + text1b
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel).text = text1

    if admin.admin == "yes" {
        (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as UISwitch).setOn(true, animated:true)

    } else if admin.admin == "no" {
        (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as UISwitch).setOn(false, animated:true)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I am now try to get the same thing. I have implemented the IBAction inside the UITableViewCell to get the switch value but I don't know hot to get the value from the TableViewController in which there is that cell with the switch... what I am missing? Should I call something inside cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set an **action** in your Custom Table View Cell to handle the change in your `UISwitch` and react to changes in it, see the following code :

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

     @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

     @IBAction func statusChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
         self.label.text = sender.on ? "On" : "Off"
     }
}
```

The above example is just used to change the text of the `UILabel` regarding the state of the `UISwitch`, you have to change it in base your requirements of course. I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you so much Victor, it took me a few minutes to figure out that I actually had to specify the custom class (Had a duh moment) but after that it worked like a charm.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen .ValueChanged of UISwitch, in YOUR_CUSTOM_CELL to make some decisions. There you can catch to "println" your data.

Answer (score 0):

Eric,

At some point in the tableview's lifecycle, you'll need to configure each UISwitch in the table cell with a target/action.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:

The `action` tells the UISwitch instance what method it should invoke when the switch is flipped by the user. The `target` tells the UISwitch instance what object is hosting that method.

Typically, you'll use the UITableViewController (or UIViewController) subclass as the target.