# Select UITableView's row when tapping on its UISwitch in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uiswitch

This question has been approached [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121139/select-uitableviews-row-when-clicking-on-uiswitch) in Objective-C. But I am working in Swift and have a similar question.

**Once successfully created, how do I select the UITableView's row when I tap on its UISwitch?**

I have a boolean in my model and would like to toggle that boolean based on the switches on/off state.

I have some programmatically created cells that contain switches...

**View Controller:**

```
var settings : [SettingItem] = [
        SettingItem(settingName: "Setting 1", switchState: true),
        SettingItem(settingName: "Setting 2", switchState: true)
    ]

override public func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomSettingCell") as! SettingCell

        let settingItem = settings[indexPath.row]
        cell.settingsLabel.text = settingItem.settingName
        cell.settingsSwitch.enabled = settingItem.switchState!

        return cell
    }
```

**based off a model in SettingItem.swift:**

```
class SettingItem: NSObject {

    var settingName : String?
    var switchState : Bool?

    init (settingName: String?, switchState : Bool?) {
        super.init()
        self.settingName = settingName
        self.switchState = switchState
    } 
}
```

**and I have some outlets in SettingCell.swift:**

```
class SettingCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var settingsLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var settingsSwitch: UISwitch!


    @IBAction func handledSwitchChange(sender: UISwitch) {
        println("switched")
    }
```

**Which produces this (please ignore the formatting):**

[image]

Comment: I answer a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354969/uiswitch-in-tableview-in-switch/29355556#29355556. I hope this help you.

Comment: @VictorSigler I'l take a look at your post, thanks Victor. Looks like I missed this when I searched before posting.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When I want events to propagate from a cell to the containing controller, I usually define a custom delegate, like this:

```
protocol SettingCellDelegate : class {
    func didChangeSwitchState(# sender: SettingCell, isOn: Bool)
}
```

use it in the cell:

```
class SettingCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var settingsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var settingsSwitch: UISwitch!

    weak var cellDelegate: SettingCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func handledSwitchChange(sender: UISwitch) {
        self.cellDelegate?.didChangeSwitchState(sender: self, isOn:settingsSwitch.on)
        ^^^^
    }
}
```

implement the protocol in the view controller and set the delegate in the cell:

```
class ViewController : UITableViewController, SettingCellDelegate {
                                              ^^^^
    override func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomSettingCell") as! SettingCell

        let settingItem = settings[indexPath.row]
        cell.settingsLabel.text = settingItem.settingName
        cell.settingsSwitch.enabled = settingItem.switchState!

        cell.cellDelegate = self
        ^^^^

        return cell
    }

#pragma mark - SettingCellDelegate

    func didChangeSwitchState(#sender: SettingCell, isOn: Bool) {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender)
        ...
    }
}
```

When the switch is tapped, the event is propagated to the view controller, with the new status and the cell itself passed as arguments. From the cell you can obtain the index path, and then do whatever you need to, such as selecting the row etc.

Comment: One doubt I have, the `var cellDelegate: SettingCellDelegate?` it would not be declared `weak` to avoid cycles in memory? I would like to know your opinion in this matter, please

Comment: @VictorSigler: you are absolutely right - it has to be `weak`, but in order for that to work the protocol must be declared as a class protocol.

Comment: @Antonio Thanks for your answer, you clarify me!! Nice

Comment: Excellent answer, @Antonio. Perhaps in the handledSwitchChange function you could have self.cellDelegate?.didChangeSwitchState(sender: self, isOn:sender.on) therefore removing the need for the settingsSwitch outlet.