# Update CoreData Value with UISwitch in UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, uiswitch

Just learning so I am sure there are much better ways to code what I have so far.  Anyways, I have a simple task list that is saved to core data.  You can segue to another VC where you can edit or create new task.  I wanted to be able to put a uiswitch in the custom cell that would allow you to set the task as complete and then reload the tableview.  I have searched all over and found this [Select UITableView's row when tapping on its UISwitch in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516730/select-uitableviews-row-when-tapping-on-its-uiswitch-in-swift/29517926) but can't seem to translate a solution.  Any help would be great.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRQ6x.png)

I am not sure if I am supposed to code the save within the custom cell or just or pass delegate.

Here is my custom cell
protocol SettingCellDelegate : class {
    func didChangeSwitchState(sender: TaskCell, isOn: Bool)
}

class TaskCell: UITableViewCell {

```
var delegate: SettingCellDelegate!

@IBOutlet weak var taskImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var arrowImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var dueDateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dueDateValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dueTimeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dueTimeValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var taskCellStatus: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var taskCellSwitchDisplay: UISwitch!
@IBAction func taskCellSwitchAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (taskCellSwitchDisplay.on) {

        taskCellStatus.text = "Completed"

    } else {

        taskCellStatus.text = "Active"

    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var taskNameValue: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    delegate = self
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    taskCellSwitchDisplay.addTarget(self, action: "switchChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

func configureCell(task: Tasks) {
    taskImage.image = UIImage(named: "Icon.png")
    arrowImage.image = UIImage(named: "arrow_filled.png")
    dueDateLabel.text = "Due Date:"
    dueDateValue.text = task.taskDate
    dueTimeLabel.text = "Due Time:"
    dueTimeValue.text = task.taskTime
    taskNameValue.text = task.taskName
    taskCellStatus.text = task.status
    //taskCellStatus.hidden = true
    if (taskCellStatus.text == "Completed") {

        taskCellSwitchDisplay.on = true


    } else {

        taskCellSwitchDisplay.on = false
    }

}

func switchChanged(taskCellSwitchDisplay: UISwitch) {
    _ = taskCellSwitchDisplay.on

    if taskCellSwitchDisplay.on == true {

        let switchValue = "Completed"

        print("Switch Variable: \(switchValue)")

        delegate.didChangeSwitchState(self, isOn: true)

    } else {

        let switchValue = "Active"

        print("Switch Variable: \(switchValue)")

        delegate.didChangeSwitchState(self, isOn: false)

    }

}
```

Here is where I am getting the delegate in my tableview

extension TaskCell: SettingCellDelegate {
    func didChangeSwitchState(sender: TaskCell, isOn: Bool)  {

```
    if isOn == true {

        print("true")


    } else {

        print("false")
    }
}
```